# Getting DHCP address in virtual machine with ubuntu 14.04 fails

Tags: virtualbox, dhclient

I run Linux 14.04 in a virtual machine istalled on windows 10. I don't get an IP address in VM Linux (Windows ok). I see that ubunt looks on a wrong DHCP server address (I guess the variable is DHCPREQUEST).

How can I change the DHCPREQUEST to the correct DHCP server address? Or can it be done by another way (the adapter on Windows PC has got a correct address).

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

select machine > settings network > adapter > attached to **Bridge Adapter**

also check advanced > adapter type to **PCnet-FASTIII** it has broader compatibility then others

ps: check the name field to be the desired physical adapter